# Volley GET Request freezes app

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm downloading a large JSON file from an API and then I write it to a file. To  GET The JSON I use a VolleySingleton class and my GET method;

```
 public void sendJSONRequest(){
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            (String) null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

But when I call sendJSONRequest() on my Activity's OnCreate method my app freezes and cease to work, you'll get an option to close the app or wait, I thought Volley was asynchronous, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably loading the large text content into a Toast will freeze the UI. The request is asynchronous. The onResponse is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the requests are asynchronous. ie: Executed in a background thread. I think the cause is because you're having a large JSON.

Try commenting the following LOC and see whether the app freezes.

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If the app does NOT freeze now, then it's because the response string is too large.

In that case, you need to perform the processing of the response in a AsyncTask too.

NOTE: You cannot display a Toast in a thread other than the UI thread. But suppose you're trying to parse the json and saving it to a SQLite db, then you can do that in an AsyncTask.

If the app still freezes after commenting the above LOC, then there's something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Ahhh now I feel stupid, I usually Log, don't know why I put a toast right there. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add timeout and max tries policy in volley request like this

```
    final int CONNTIMEOUT=30000;

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,urlBuffer.toString(),null,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    Log.i(Constants.NETLOG, "Volley response= " + response.toString());
                                    //Success response

                                    if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
                                    {dialog.dismiss();}
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e(Constants.NETLOG, "VolleyError response= " + error.toString());
                            if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
                            {dialog.dismiss();}
                            //Error in response
                        }
                    });
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                            CONNTIMEOUT,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                    Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext).add(jsonObjReq);
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Please wait", "Processing.........");
```

Once this is done, do your success response process in a background thread, if there is huge data coming as per your question using `AsyncTask` to free your UI thread and prevent the blocking/crashing. And rather than making a `Toast` message in `onResponse`, verify result using `Log.v("NETLOG", response.toString());`